# Using function as class member in C++

Tags: c++, oop, hash

I have came from Java, I have some knowledge of C++ and C, but not deep. I am creating hashtable class, it will encapsulate storing values and keys. But the question is what is a better approach to pass, for example, in constructor custom function which will calculate a hash key in the table.

In java I would use function (interface) setting it as class member. What is the best practice to do this in C++, use the function pointer as member? Please suggest how to implement this.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::map` (or the unsorted variant)?

Comment: @Mat I assume this is a homework assignment. To the OP, it would be helpful if you mocked up the constructor signature and hash-method signature you would be expecting, as there are many possible solutions to this question.

Comment: Is your class a template, or are the key and value types fixed?

Comment: You should search the internet for "c++ hashmap".  If you don't use the libraries, you could refer to the examples.

Comment: If you need to implement this as an exercise, look at how the Standard Library implements `std::map` and follow that design. There's no constructor, but there are specialized hashing functions for the types of things you need to hash: `std::hash`.

Comment: I need to create my own hashmap, I have template class, I need to have ability to pass custom function to HashMap object which will be used to calculate key.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ practice is to parametrize your class with callable type that will calculate the hash:

```
template<class Key, class Value, class Hash> class hashtable;
```

This allows to have any callable object as your hash function, be it plain function or functor object.

Then pass callable object in the constructor:

```
template<class Key, class Value, class Hash>
class hashtable
{
  hashtable(Hash h);
};
```

This allows you to specify different hash functions without creating new classes.

Finally, to make declaration and construction of `hashtable`s more convenient, we specify default template parameters and constructor arguments:

```
template<class Key, class Value, class Hash = std::hash<Key> >
class hashtable
{
  hashtable(Hash h = Hash());
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The same as in Java. But what if need to change hash function in runtime ?

Comment: You could have another method - `rehash(Hash new_hash)`. If you are concerned that this new hash function would have to have to be of the same type as the old one, you can hide concrete type in `std::function`.